# JSP Parsing url and matching key words

Tags: javascript, jsp, url

Here is my question, I am using jsp script, trying to match a key word in requesting url and do something:

```
    <script>
     $url = '${pageContext.request.requestURL}';

    if("${fn:contains(url, 'key')}" == true){
        ...
    }
....
```

But this doest work... I am not sure where the problem is but I want it to be like when url contains this string, go in to the if condition.

Thank you

Comment: `<script>` is mostly used for JavaScript, `$url` is used in shell programming, are you sure you're using JSP?

Comment: It's java script code block in jsp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing JSP/EL and JavaScript as if they run in sync. This is wrong. JSP/EL runs in webserver and produces HTML code which get executed in webbrowser. JavaScript (JS) is part of the generated HTML code and runs in webbrowser only.

You need to do it either fully in JSP/EL, or fully in JavaScript. You can use JSP/EL to dynamically generate JS code which get later executed when the page arrives at browser. Rightclick page in browser, do *View Source* to see what JSP/EL has generated. You should not see any line of JSP/EL. You should only see HTML/JS code. It's exactly *that* JS code which get executed then.

You're using a JSP EL function to test a JS variable which isn't in the variable scope at that moment at all. This is not going to work. It can only test JSP/EL variables.

Here's how you could do it in pure JS:

```
<script>
    var url = window.location.href;

    if (url.indexOf('key') > -1) {
       // ...
    }
</script>
```

If you *really* insist in doing it using JSP/EL, you could do as follows:

```
<script>
    var url = '${pageContext.request.requestURI}';

    if (${fn:contains(pageContext.request.requestURI, 'key')}) {
       // ...
    }
</script>
```

This will then generate the following JS code (rightclick page in browser and *View Source* to see it):

```
<script>
    var url = '/some/uri';

    if (true) {
       // ...
    }
</script>
```

But this makes no sense. Whatever functional requirement you need to solve, you need to think twice about the right approach. Feel free to ask a new question about solving the concrete functional requirement the proper way.

Comment: thank you very much, but I'm not sure what you mean by saying the JSP/EL solution does not make sense... btw, when I am trying to apply the jsp/el solution you gave, it reports me a "missing semicolon" syntax error in the if condition.

Comment: Just use the pure JS approach. Why doing it the hard and confusing way if it can be done simple with 1 language?

Comment: You're welcome. I hope that you now understand that JSP and JavaScript are NOT the same language and have absolutely nothing to do with each other expect of the first 4 characters of the language name and a less or more similar syntax. It's like as car to carpet. I have already linked it in my answer to your previous question, but here it is again as you seem to not have read it at all: [our JSP tag wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info). It also contains a part which explains the relation with JavaScript (and a bunch of good JSP tutorial links).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a parameter that the page was requested with, use `${param.paramName}`.  So in this case `${param.key}`.  See implicit objects in [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html).  And if you just want to check it has a value try `${not empty param.key}`.